# Regex doesn't work when newline is at the end of the string

Tags: regex, scala

Exercise: given a string with a name, then space or newline, then email, then maybe newline and some text separated by newlines capture the name and the domain of email.

So I created the following:

```
val regexp = "^([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\\s|\\n)\\w+@(\\w+\\.\\w+)(?:.|\\r|\\n)*".r

def fun(str: String): String = {
  val result = str match {
    case regexp(name, domain) => name + ' ' + domain
    case _ => "invalid"
  }
  result
}
```

And started testing:

```
scala> val input = "oleg oleg@email.com"
scala> fun(input)
res17: String = oleg email.com
scala> val input = "oleg\noleg@email.com"
scala> fun(input)
res18: String = oleg email.com
scala> val input = """oleg
     | oleg@email.com
     | 7bdaf0a1be3"""

scala> fun(input)
res19: String = oleg email.com
scala> val input = """oleg
     | oleg@email.com
     | 7bdaf0a1be3
     | """

scala> fun(input)
res20: String = invalid
```

Why doesn't the regexp capture the string with the newline at the end?

Comment: Both tests 3 and 4 failed for me until I added `.stripMargin` at the end of each.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/wiL6D5IKQuWnT9I149o3JQ

Comment: @jwvh Do you know, how to change the regexp, so that `.` matched \n without the need for `.stripMargin`? In Perl it could be done with `/s` modifier. But here it seems impossible.

Comment: What you want is `(?s)` at the beginning of the regex pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part `(?:\\s|\\n)` can be shortened to `\s` as it will also match a newline, and as there is still a space before the emails where you are using multiple lines it can be `\s+` to repeat it 1 or more times.

Matching any character like this `(?:.|\\r|\\n)*` if very inefficient due to the alternation. You can use either `[\S\s]*` or use an inline modifier `(?s)` to make the dot match a newline.

But using your pattern to just get the name and the domain of the email you don't have to match what comes after it, as you are using the 2 capturing groups in the output.

```
^([a-zA-Z]+)\s+\w+@(\w+\.\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ValPrT/1)

If you do want to match all that follows, you can use:

```
val regexp = """(?s)^([a-zA-Z]+)\s+\w+@(\w+\.\w+).*""".r

def fun(str: String): String = {
  val result = str match {
    case regexp(name, domain) => name + ' ' + domain
    case _ => "invalid"
  }
  result
}
```

[Scala demo](https://ideone.com/zXh3kX)

**Note** that this pattern `\w+@(\w+\.\w+)` is very limited for matching an email